# Python Gmail Parsing and Regex

Tags: python, regex, email

My Python function scans Gmails for stock options symbols. So far it parses the subject line using the following code. Instead, I would like it to parse the message body, since often there are too many symbols to fit in the subject. A similar regex could probably work, however the line containing symbols is repeated twice in the message body (see [sample attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPCmb.png)). So the regex should stop once it reaches the end of line character.

I will appreciate your help with repurposing the regex!

```
def parse_symbols_from_email_to_list(email_msg):
    if email_msg['Subject'].find("Following list of symbols were added") != -1:
        symbols_list = re.findall(r'\.[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]+\.*[0-9]+', email_msg['Subject'])
        symbols_list = list(dict.fromkeys(symbols_list))
        return symbols_list
```

Comment: What is the end of line character in this case? Is it the period in the sentence `.` ?

Comment: There is a period at the end of the line, but there are also periods within the strings to be picked up. So maybe it is best to use the newline character?!

Comment: I agree, I think I would look for a period followed by a newline to mark the end of the pattern

Comment: What's the problem? Get unique matches? `set(re.findall(r'\.[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?', email_msg['Subject']))`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to `:.*?\.(.*),.*\.(.*)\..*\nA`

It will catch the first `:` up until the first line break followed by the letter `A`

with your code it'll look something like:

```
def parse_symbols_from_email_to_list(email_msg):
    if email_msg['Subject'].find("Following list of symbols were added") != -1:
        symbols_list = re.match(':.*?\.(.*),.*\.(.*)\..*\nA', email_msg['Subject'])
        symbols_list = [symbols_list[1], symbols_list[2]]
        return symbols_list
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using set data structure while getting keys from your symbols_list, so our code will look like:

```
def parse_symbols_from_email_to_list(email_msg):
if email_msg['Subject'].find("Following list of symbols were added") != -1:
    symbols_list = re.findall(r'\.[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]+\.*[0-9]+', email_msg['Subject'])
    symbols_list = list(set(dict.fromkeys(symbols_list)))
    return symbols_list
```

Comment: OP isn't asking for a regex to scan email addresses. OP wants a way to find stock symbols in an email body. Please read the questions you answer carefully. [answer].